# Cannot get ADO connection working on a classic ASP website running in IIS Express on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: asp-classic, ado, windows-7-x64, iis-express, jet

I have a legacy classic ASP website that I need to do some maintenance work on. My development machine is running Windows 7 64 bit, Visual Studio 2012 and IIS Express 8.0.

The ASP app is backed by a Microsoft Access database.

The website runs fine until it tries to establish a connection to the database, where it fails with the following:

> 0x800a0e7a - ADODB.Connection: Provider cannot be found. It may not be
>   properly installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ASP process is running as 64-bit and it is trying to use the Jet database engine then that won't work because there is no 64-bit version of Jet. If that is the case then you can either

- install the 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine (ACE), available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255), and tweak the connection parameters as required, or
- get the ASP process to run as 32-bit

Comment: I tried to install the 64 bit version, but I could not because I have Office 2010 32 bit installed. How can I force IIS Express to run the ASP app in 32 bit mode? I've tried adding `enable32BitAppOnWin64="true"` to the app pool config in applicationhost.config, but no luck...

Comment: @GiddyUpHorsey RE: "How can I force IIS Express to run the ASP app in 32 bit mode?" - Sorry, but I can't offer any advice on that beyond adding the [tag:iis-express] tag to your question and seeing if somebody else picks up on it.

Comment: I managed to get the app running in a 32 bit process and connecting to the database now works. The solution is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16226897/80282).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem you mention in a follow up comment.

> I tried to install the 64 bit version, but I could not because I have
>   Office 2010 32 bit installed.

You can force the 64 bit version of the Access Database Engine (ACE) [from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255) to install with the 'passive' switch:

```
AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe /passive
```